# Evaluate $\iint dydx$ on the domain $0\leq r\leq1$, ${\pi}/{3}\leq\theta \leq{2\pi}/{3}$

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> I need to evaluate 
>   $\displaystyle\iint \color{red}{dydx}\;\;\;,\bigg\{\frac{\pi}{3}\leq\theta \leq\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigg\}\;\;\;\;,0\leq r\leq1$ 
>   $\color{blue}{\text{without using polar coordinates}}$.

My attempt:

The equation of the two lines will be $y=\pm\tan(60)x=\pm\sqrt3x$

The intersection points of the lines with the circle will be $\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore:
$$\int_{x=-1/2}^{x=0}\int_{y=-\sqrt3 x}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx+\int_{x=0}^{x=1/2}\int_{y=\sqrt3x}^{y=\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx=\dots\approx \boxed{2\times0.478..}$$

But area of circle is $\pi r^2$ and here the area should be $\boxed{\frac{\pi}{6}}$

> I can't find my mistake

It looks similar to [Evaluate $\iint dy\,dx;\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\theta \leq\frac{3\pi}{4};0\leq r\leq2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377261/evaluate-iint-dy-dx-frac-pi4-leq-theta-leq-frac3-pi40-leq-r-leq2)

but here the radius is diffrente and also the angles

[image]

Comment: How about just saying that the answer will be 1/6 the area of a circle with radius one?  This is not using polar coordinates, or any integration at all.  I don't see anything else as necessary.

Comment: What wrong with just stating that this is the area of the sector of the unit circle where $\pi/3 < \theta < 2\pi/3$ (i.e. $\pi/6$)?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I need to do it using integrals

Comment: @Nehorai show us how you find $0.478$

Comment: It is long and useless

Comment: @Math-fun It is not the same, look the radius, and $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$\iint_{A} dxdy= \text{Area of A}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$
If you must use Cartesians (although I stress that the above is correct!) then at least by symmetry we can take double the integral of the sector with $x>0$. It will be easier to integrate over $y$ first, since we won't need to change our boundaries. We have $\sqrt{3}x<y<\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$, and $0<x<1/2$, so the integral is $$\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_{\sqrt{3}x}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}dydx=\int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-\sqrt{3}x dx=\frac{\pi}{12}$$
which is a standard 1-d integral (you can do it by substitution)

Comment: I need dydx (it is in red color)

Comment: They are the same...